# How do I get HttpCompression (GZip) to work with URL Routing (Extensionless URLs) on IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, gzip, url-routing, http-compression

Okay,

URL Routing is great. Extensionless URLS, SEO friendly etc.  However, it seems that IIS 6 doesn't perform compression on sites that use Extensionless URLs.

WildCard Mapping is on so Asp.Net can process the extensionless files, but is there any way to set these resources to be gzipped?

Comment: I actually don't think HttpCompression works on IE6, at least through IIS.  Had a similar problem during the launch of a previous project.  No  one, internal to the company, could see the site, and we found that it was due to everyone having IE6 installed.

We had to remove the compression.

Comment: Well, Http Compression only gets sent if the Browser requests it.  If IE6 doesn't support it, then it won't send a header.  And anyway, who seriously cares about IE6? :-) I do all my testing in FF3 and then make sure it doesn't look horrible in IE6.  The Compression isn't happening on FF3... so the server isn't sending the compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following product may be useful:  [Port80's httpZip](http://www.port80software.com/products/httpzip)

Disclaimer: I haven't tried the product, and don't have any affiliation with the company.  I've simply been keeping it on my radar in case bandwidth costs ever went through the roof, after I learned IIS6 built in compression wasn't the bees knees.

One of the httpZip [FAQ pages](http://www.port80software.com/products/httpzip/faq.asp#hzoniis6) states:
"Controlling compression by MIME type: IIS 6.0 built-in compression uses the file extension and/or location to determine whether a file should be compressed or not. If you need to control HTTP compression by MIME (for example, if you have an application file like ASP or an ISAPI filter that is outputting content with different MIMEs), httpZip's granular controls for compression by MIME type are the only way to accomplish this on IIS 6.0."

To address the point raised in JackM's comment, one of the product's claims (at the first link above) is "Flawless decompression ensured by real-time browser compatibility checking. [... then later ...] IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003: A robust compression engine is built into the Web server, but suffers from a fatal flaw – it lacks browser compatibility checking."

Comment: BTW, search on "httpZip" to find some other questions here that mention the product.

Comment: Thanks for the httpZip Comment.